# Decoding Javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to capture values within the URL:

```
www.domain.com/foo/bar#/15%22|24%22
```

I want: 15%22|24%22

What I'm using is `window.location.hash.split('#')[1]` which grabs the data, at which point I want to then decode it.

```
var pageType = window.location.hash.split('#') [1];
return decodeURIComponent(pageType);
```

This would then return 15"|24" which is what I want. When I test this out in Google Chrome console I get a syntax error of "Illegal return statement" ....maybe this isn't the right approach to be testing it this way. Am I missing something, or should this be handled in a different way?

Comment: Can you show us what you're getting instead?

Comment: Also, is there supposed to be a `/` after the `#` in your example value?

Comment: My apologies, I went back to edit my post and never saved it prior to closing my screen. Yes @talemyn, there is suppose to be a `/` after the `#` in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use `return` if you are inside of a function. If you are just running those lines directly, you aren't inside of anything that you can return from.

You should always be working with your browser's development tools window open (`F12`). With the dev tools open, you can click to the tab called "console".  This window will always show you your JavaScript errors but it can also be used as a window to write messages to for debugging purposes. `console.log(message)` is how  you write messages to that window. If you look at the sample code below you will see that I am writing out the results of the operation to the console.

This code works:

```js
var test = "www.domain.com/foo/bar#/15%22|24%22";

var pageType = test.split('#')[1];

// Remove the leading slash
pageType = pageType.substr(1,pageType.length-1);

console.log(decodeURIComponent(pageType));
```

Comment: I updated my post. I edited my original post, but failed to save it prior to closing my screen.

Comment: @Brando I have updated my answer to address your latest question.

Comment: thanks for the info. I'm guessing that I could add some regex to the test var that's defined and use regex to be a bit more dynamic? Or is there a more robust solution to take?

Comment: @Brando For this situation, regEx would only be a slight improvement. This solution is simple enough as it is.